# Goland: Install package "assert" without leaving Goland?

Tags: goland

I want to install the well-known "assert" package from https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert

I can remember "assert", but not the full URL.

I could leave the IDE and use my favorite search engine,
but maybe there is way to install and import the "assert" package
without leaving Goland?

Expected result:

```
 import (
+   "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "testing"
 )
```

And `go.mod` and `go.sum` get updated.

With other words: I want to get to this string ("github.com/stretchr/testify/assert") without leaving Goland.

Comment: `go get github.com/stretchr/testify/assert` in GoLand Terminal, then import that package in any place of Go code, GoLand will prompt you to import it. Second way is to add `require` directive in `go.mod`, press _Alt+Enter_ and select _Syncronize dependencies_ action.

Comment: @s0xzwasd With other words: I want to get to this string ("github.com/stretchr/testify/assert") without leaving Goland. I don't remember this string and I don't wan to rember this string in the future. All I want to remember is that I need to install an assert package from testify.

Comment: Well, I believe you are looking for something like Python Packages feature: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html. Please follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4201.